# Running a code to multiple sheet with calling a sub

Tags: vba, excel

I am applying a code to more than one worksheet. However, the catch is that I am calling a sub in loop( Call sort) which contains code and at the end calls other sub and so on. I want all the subs to be called for one sheet and then go to next sheet and do the same task. I have three sheets named "5", "6" and "7"(can be more than that also). Here is the code I am applying:

```
Sub code()
Dim wsarray As Sheets

Set wsarray = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("5", "6", "7"))

For Each sheetobject In wsarray
sheetobject.Select
Call Sort
Next
End Sub
```

This code gives correct output for only 7. I don't know how to go around this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about using arrays with sheet names, but an alternative is to loop through all sheets, and if it's 5,6, or 7 then run the code:

```
dim wsht as Worksheet

for each wsht in Activeworkbook
    If wsht.name = "5" or wsht.name = "6" or wsht.name = "7" Then
         With worksheets(wsht.name)
              Call Sort
         end with
    End if
next wsht
```

edit: Or, this might work with Arrays -- I would declare your own array to store those first, then call that array:
(adapted from [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/357663-loop-through-array-sheets.html)

```
Sub Test()

Dim myArray(1 To 3) As String, x
myArray(1) = "5"
myArray(2) = "6"
myArray(3) = "7"

For Each x In myArray
    Sheets(x).Select
    Call Sort
Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same sub name in every sheet do it like this:

```
public sub subname()
dim wsht as Worksheet

for each wsht in Worksheets
    Activeworkbook.sheets(wsht.name).sort
next wsht
end sub
```